# What is the name for the kind of eye-bolt used to secure bicycle fender stays

Tags: hardware, fastener

I need a part that looks like this: it consists of an "eye"-bolt with a nut and washer which allows this part to be attached to a rod/tube of the right diameter.

These "bolts" are commonly used for attaching bicycle fenders; the picture is from a bike company. However, I want to know if these are available in arbitrary sizes, i.e. multiple combinations of:

1. Shank length and thread pitch
2. 'Head' size and hole dia

etc

[image: Mystery nut]

Comment: Try searching for "stay binder".

Comment: Please avoid putting a question in the subject that also isn't in the body.  Your subject is "what's the name" and your body is more of a  "where do I find it" feel.

Comment: Well that went ususually sideways. I already knew these things are used for fenders. What I'm looking for is a non-bicycle source - for connecting stuff of *other* sizes for a DIY project.

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be called, fender eyelet bolts, eyelet bolts, or bicycle fender bolts. There is a link I found for Fender Eyelet Bolts, 5mm [here](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/vo-eyelet-bolts-5mm-pair-closed-type.html).

Answer (score 0):

For non-US readers of this question: In some parts of the world these are called "mudguard bolts"

[Example](https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/mudguards/sks-mudguard-bolts-nuts-endcaps-for-bluemels/)

[image]

> SKS Mudguard Bolts, Nuts & Endcaps for use when fitting ... mudguards.

Answer (score -1):

Check out McMaster-Carr Supply they are online and would be a good place to start. Start out  with latch or swing bolts. Or Reid Tool Supply

Comment: The question was about the name of the item.  This doesn't really answer the question, just gives advice on how to search somewhere else for it.

Comment: Already spoke to someone at McMaster-Carr - they don't have anything like this and don't know what this is called.